# Meaning of "The nature of your imagining makes the claim that there couldn’t be a hearing of the imagined sort seem mistaken"

Tags: meaning

I need help with understanding this sentence:

> The nature of your imagining makes the claim that there couldn’t be a hearing of the imagined sort seem mistaken.

Comment: It's nonsense. Source?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are having auditory hallucinations; that you are 'hearing things', and that you describe your experience, or 'imagining' to me. The sentence might be my (very convoluted)response. Maybe paraphrased like this?

'The fact that you are having this experience means that people who say such experiences do not exist are wrong'.

Comment: Holy crap. That's plausible.

Comment: Maybe that's what the intended meaning is but it isn't what the sentence actually says. The sentence in the OP is clearly stated as drawing a conclusion from an imagined event not a real experience. Agree with @preston it is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is badly written, though I believe I understand what the author is attempting (poorly) to convey:

> {The nature of your imagining} {makes} {the claim that} {there couldn’t be a hearing of the imagined sort} {seem mistaken.}

My interpretation (to supplement @badspell's answer):

> Based on your experience, the claim that auditory hallucinations
>   don't exist is false.

Comment: Why have you added in an _(s)_ after ‘seem’? That would certainly make the sentence ungrammatical. As it is, though it is badly written, it is grammatically quite correct.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, because I read it as referring the first subject "the nature." ...the nature of your imagining seems mistaken. I could completely be misreading the sentence. Perhaps I need to come back in ten minutes and reread it again.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't understand how the sentence is grammatically correct as it stands.

Comment: “The nature of your imaginging _makes_ (the claim that…) _seem_ mistaken”. _Makes_ here is ‘forces to’ or ‘results in’; not ‘forwards [the claim]’. Otherwise, there are some elements in the sentence that cannot be made to fit in (at least as far as I can work out).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah! Thank you for clarifying that. It reads more clearly now, though I think my interpretation of the meaning still stands. Edited my post.